# UIView with custom shape

Tags: ios, uiview, custom-controls

I want to have a UIElement (any of UIView, UIButton, UILabel etc.) with custom shape lets say a triangle.
How do you suggest to achieve it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample of a UIView subclass (triangle):

```
@implementation TriangleView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);

    CGContextMoveToPoint   (ctx, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));  // top left
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));  // mid right
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));  // bottom left

    CGContextClosePath(ctx);

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 241/255.0, 241/255.0, 241/255.0, 1);
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);

}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. Will this actually convert our view to triangle ? If I have a gesture recognizer added to the view, will it fire if I tape on empty place of the rect where triangle is not drawn ?

Comment: I don't know because I didn't try, but you can test it.

Comment: This won't convert your UIView into a triangle, it will just draw a triangle inside it. If you want to define a custom tap area, you need to override `pointInside:withEvent` method.