# How am I supposed to implement point(inside:with:)?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am trying to create a non-rectangular shaped `UIView`, with a non-rectangular shaped touch area. I already know how to draw my shape with bezier paths.

According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381343/uiview-with-custom-shape#comment37599650_22382017), I need to override `point(inside:with:)` to create a custom shaped touch area.

So I tried this:

```
class MyView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: .zero)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.midY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        UIColor.red.setFill()
        path.fill()
    }

    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        print("point(inside:with:) called")

        func isInRegion(_ point: CGPoint) -> Bool {
            return (0...bounds.midX).contains(point.x) || (bounds.midY...bounds.maxY).contains(point.y)
        }

        guard let touches = event?.touches(for: self) else { return false }
        guard !touches.isEmpty else { return false }

        print("passed all the guards")
        let first = touches.first!
        print("first touch: \(first.location(in: self))")

        return touches.map { $0.location(in: self) }.contains(where: isInRegion)
    }
}
```

The `draw` method draws a red L shape. And I tried enable touch only inside the L shape.

I created a `MyView` called `blueView`, made its background blue so that the touch area is red and the non-touch area is blue.

I also added a regular green `UIView` under part of the blue, like this:

[image]

I enabled user interactions for both of these views and added `UITapGestureRecogniser`s, so that if the red area is tapped, `blue view tapped` will be printed. If the green view is tapped, `green view tapped` will be printed.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    blueView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    greenView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    blueView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(blueViewTapped)))
    greenView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(greenViewTapped)))
}

@objc func blueViewTapped() {
    print("Blue view tapped")
}

@objc func greenViewTapped() {
    print("Green view tapped")
}
```

When I run the app and tap the red bit, only `point(inside:with:) called` is printed twice and nothing else. I expected `blue view tapped` and all the other print statements in `point(inside:with:)` to be run as well. If I tap the blue bit, the same message is printed twice again. If I tap the green bit that is covered by the blue bit, `Green view tapped` is printed after `point(inside:with:) called` is printed twice.

Why is `blue view tapped` not printed? I must have implemented `point(inside:with:)` wrongly, right?

EDIT:

After some debugging, I found out that the reason why `point(inside:with:)` is not returning true is because `event.allTouches` is empty. This is very strange because I am 100% sure that I touched the view!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using `UIBezierPath` to draw the area you want to tap, you can detect points inside your non-rectangular area by saving a reference to your path and using `.contains(_:)`:

```
class MyView: UIView {

    var path: UIBezierPath!

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: .zero)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.midY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        UIColor.red.setFill()
        path.fill()
    }

    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {

        print("path containsPoint?", path.contains(point))

        return path.contains(point)

    }
}
```

Comment: Oh god! I can't believe I didn't even notice that there is a `point` parameter passed into this method! Your answer made me realise that! I always thought I need to get the touched points from the `UIEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

[point(inside:with:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622533-point) is used by [hitTest(_:with:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest) to determine whether subviews should be traversed or not.

In your case, if user taps on blue area you should return false.

You can do it simply by checking

```
if (point is inside blue+red rect) {
    return !(point is inside blue)
} else {
    return false
}
```

You don't need to test for touches:

```
override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    print("point(inside:with:) called")

    func isInRegion(_ point: CGPoint) -> Bool {
        return (0...bounds.midX).contains(point.x) || (bounds.midY...bounds.maxY).contains(point.y)
    }
    let a = isInRegion(point)
    print(a)
    return a
}
```

Comment: That's what I did, isn't it? I wrote a `isInRegion` function and used that to check if any of the touches are in the L region. Did I implement `isInRegion` wrong?

Comment: @Sweeper: From the code, it seems you have red and blue as separate views. I think these should be part of the same view. If they are meant to be separate views then point(inside:with:) should be implemented in their superview.

Comment: They _are_ the same view. I _drew_ the red onto the blue view. The red is just a filled in `UIBezierPath`.

Comment: @Sweeper: I don't think you need to test for touch event. guard let touches = event?.touches(for: self) else { return false } this was returning as false. Your isInRegion function is correct. If I pass point to that function, it gives correct response.

Comment: Actually, after some debugging, the problem is that `event.allTouches` is empty. Any ideas?